# what is diffrence between Configuration binding and IOption Pattern in dotnet core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I know there are two ways to inject configuration into my other layers class:

first one **Configuration binding**:

```
services.AddConfiguration()  // enable Configuration Services
var config = new WeblogConfiguration();
Configuration.Bind("Weblog", config);      //  <--- This
services.AddSingleton(config);
```

usage:

```
public class PostsController : Controller
{
    PostRepository PostRepo { get; }
    WeblogConfiguration Config  { get; }
    
    public PostsController(PostRepository postRepo, 
                           WeblogConfiguration config)
    {
        PostRepo = postRepo;
        Config = config;
    }
    ...
}
```

and **IOption Pattern**:

```
services.Configure<WeblogConfiguration>(option => Configuration.GetSection("WeblogConfiguration").Bind(option));
            services.AddOptions();
```

usage:

```
public class PostsController : Controller
{
    PostRepository PostRepo { get; }
    WeblogConfiguration Config  { get; }
    
    public PostsController(PostRepository postRepo, 
                           IOptions<WeblogConfiguration> config)
    {
        PostRepo = postRepo;
        Config = config.Value;
    }
    ...
}
```

I want to know the difference between these methods and the cons and pros for each of them.

Comment: I think rather than asking here, it might be best to just look at the documentation for IOptions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0 . As for the pros and cons, well that borders on subjectivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far only one difference come into my mind:

The possibility to reload the configuration.

When you bind your `WeblogConfiguration` and add it as singleton it will be loaded once and never changes.

Once you use the `IOptions` pattern you could use the `reloadOnChange` argument when adding the json file and will get updated values via the `IOptions.Value` method.